# Vaadin 24: npm issue

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-spring-boot

Using,

```
Spring boot: 3.2.1
Vaadin: 24.1.4
```

I am using below command on my local machine and everything is working fine.

```
gradle clean vaadinBuildFrontend build -DproductionMode=true -x test --stacktrace
```

However,
when same command is executed in gitlab pipeline it throws an exception/error:

```
com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: npm install. Some dependencies are not installed.
```

I am also getting following logs:

```
npm ERR ! code EPROTO
npm ERR ! request to https://registery.npmjs.org/@open-wc%2fdedupe-mixin failed
```

#### Expected behavior

Application should successfully build and compile in gitlab as well.

#### Minimal reproducible example

NA

#### Versions

- Vaadin / Flow version: 24.1.4
- Java version: 17
- OS version:
- Browser version (if applicable):
- Application Server (if applicable):
- IDE (if applicable): IntelliJ

Comment: Can your CI talk to the internet and fetch files from https://registery.npmjs.org ?

Comment: It was working before without any issues. However, I am facing this issue after upgrading from Vaadin 23.0 to 24.1.