# Migrating from Vaadin 23.0 to Vaadin 24.1.4: No Package.json found issue

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-spring-boot

Using,

```
Vaadin 24.1.4
Vaadin flow 24.1.5
Spring boot 3.1.2
```

Command running well on my local machine:

```
gradle clean vaadinBuildFrontend build -DproductionMode=true -x test --stacktrace
```

However, when I run gitlab job it fails and getting this in log file:

```
"345 error pnpm":{

"message":{
"code": "ERR_PNPM_NO_IMPORTER_MANIFEST_FOUND"
},
"err":{
"message": "No package.json was found in "/home/{user}/dev/{project-repo}/build/flow-frontend/form"
}
```

Comment: So is this progress over
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76789933/vaadin-24-npm-issue ? Is
the `package.json` actually missing?  It should be generated by the
plugin... What do you mean by "vaadin 24.1.**4**", when you next say you
are using "vaadin flow 24.1.**5**"?